# Obtener documentos ordenados por la cantidad de elementos de un array

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express

Estoy utilizando mongoose en mi api en node. Tengo mi scheme que tiene un atributo del tipo array que solo guarda IDS *participants*.
¿Cómo hago para obtener todos los registros ordenados por la cantidad de participants? De mayor a menor.
Utilicé lo que es `.sort({participants: -1})`, pero no los ordena por la cantidad de *participants*.

```
const x = Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ownerId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Usuario',
        required: true
    },
    creationDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    partyDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    startTime: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    endTime:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    participants: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Usuario",
    }],
```

Comment: Por lo que se puede  ver ahí, `participants` es un Object, no un Array, por lo que puede que el problema del sort esté relacionado con eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un valor auxiliar (por ejemplo llamado `size`) y ordenar por ese valor:

- Primero usar `$set` para crear el campo auxiliar que utiliza `$size` para guardar el tamaño del array.
- Después ordenar utilizando `$sort`.
- Y por úlitmo `$project` para no mostrar el campo auxiliar  creado.

```
modelo.aggregate({
  "$set": {
    "size": {
      "$size": "$participants"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$sort": {
    "size": -1
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "size": 0
  }
})
```

Ejemplo [aquí](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pu4X6WMu40c)

Comment: wow jamas iba a poder hacerlo solo, sabia que era por la mano del aggregate pero iba a tardar bastante en comprenderlo. Muchisimas gracias

Comment: De nada! Si la respuesta ha sido útil y ha solucionado el problema se agradece marcarla como aceptada.